# Possible bug tracking buffer progress with AVPlayerItem.loadedTimeRanges

Tags: ios, avqueueplayer

I'm running into some strange issues with AVQueuePlayer.  I'll first explain the purpose of my implementation, then go over the issues I am hitting.

Running: iPhone5s, iOS 10.1.1, LTE connection

Video: Progressively downloading a video. .mp4, 5mb, 4 second duration.

The purpose of the implementation is to play a progressively downloaded video that loops seamlessly.  The video won't contain any sounds.

I'm using an AVQueuePlayer (supporting iOS 9 and up) to loop videos.  I set it up the same way Apple recommended.  Which is to listen for the current player item to change and then move the player item to the end of the queue.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/avloopplayer/Listings/Projects_VideoLooper_VideoLooper_QueuePlayerLooper_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014695-Projects_VideoLooper_VideoLooper_QueuePlayerLooper_swift-DontLinkElementID_11

I am hitting 2 issues.

Issue 1: My designer gave me a video that contains a video track and an audio track.  Durations are the same.  I am able to track the buffer progress by checking the current player item loadedTimeRanges.  However, when the video loops, it isn't seamless.  So we tried a video without the audio track and hit Issue 2.

Issue 2: Testing the same video, but this video contains only a video track.  The video loops amazingly.  It's seamless.  However, when checking the loadedTimeRanges to track the buffer progress, the duration will remain 0 until the video has completely loaded.  Then the duration will report the total duration of the video.

Is Issue2 a bug?  I also find it strange that removing the audio track creates a much more seamless loop.

I've provided my code below that is used to check seconds buffered. Note that it will return a duration of 0 if the playerItem.loadedTimeRanges.first.timeRangeValue doesn't exist.  I can confirm that value does exist and the duration is properly returned when testing both issues.

```
public var secondsBuffered: Float64 {

    if let playerItem = self.player?.currentItem {

        if let loadedTimeRange = playerItem.loadedTimeRanges.first?.timeRangeValue {

            let duration: Float64 = CMTimeGetSeconds(loadedTimeRange.duration)

            return duration
        }
    }

    return 0
}
```